# Android: Relationship between minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Tags: android

I've read everything in the Google documentation that I could find regarding `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` but I'm still not entirely sure how to use these properly.

My current application has a `minSdkVersion` of 8 and a `targetSdkVersion` also of 8, and works fine as such.

I changed my `targetSdkVersion` to 18 and suddenly half of my application is no longer functioning as expected. Even some simple HTTP requests were not working.

From what I understood from reading the docs, `targetSdkVersion` is for using features of a certain level of API, is this correct? Why were simple HTTP requests not functioning as expected when targeting 18? Are they used differently?

If someone could give a short, clean explanation on how these two attributes work, I would be very grateful.

Also, if I keep my target at 8, will it work okay on newer devices?

Comment: do u have the sdk for '18' properly installed?  did you properly do a 'clean' & 'build' ?

Comment: @RobertRowntree I have another test project in the same workspace that targets 18 and it works fine.

Comment: if your env is ok, try building testing the SDK's 'sample API' apps...

Comment: On newer SDK versions some functions could be "Deprecated", it means, for Example, if you use some functions in targetSdkVersion=18 that have been deprecated since version 15, it can bring some errors and warnings, so be sure when you are making an app choose targetSDKVersion higher than minSDKVersion to support newer OS versions.

Comment: if env is good , maybe u have to focus on debugging the http stuff by looking more closely at WIRE & at HEADERS there?

Comment: @RobertRowntree I will, thanks! But why would such a simple thing as http networking be different in SDK18?

Comment: @Arshak92 So you're saying that if I leave my target at 8, then a newer device will not be able to run my application?

Comment: HttpClient packages, HttpUrlConnection packages are both pretty dynamic??  I can not point to anything specific ,but as always, mind the info from your logs and from your exceptions...

Comment: @PaulG Your device will run the application, but some errors and warnings are possible, so that's why it is better to choose the latest targetSDKVersion so you could handle errors if there will be in newer OS versions

Answer (score 4):

minSdk is the minimum api level that the device should have to be able to install your app.

In your code you can use all functions that are available since targetSdk or lower.

Example:
if your targetSdk is 14 and your minSdk is 8, and you want to use a method that is available since sdk 11, before you call the method you would have to check whether the device's sdk is 11 or higher.

If you use functions that require a higher api level than your minSdk, your code will compile but it will crash if the function is called on a device lower than targetSdk. That's why you have to check for it before you call the method or use the class.